# USe CallableStatement for Oracle Functions with ROWTYPE Parameters

Tags: oracle, jdbc

To call a Oracle Procedure with a Rowtype Parameter i've got a solution. My Problem are the functions.
In the Case of Procedures i build a String like a PL/SQL Script to fill the ROWTYPE Fields and call my Procedure:

```
DECLARE 
   r_tmp Test_table%ROWTYPE; 

BEGIN  
   r_tmp.ID := ?; 
   r_tmp.YFE_ID := ?; 
   r_tmp.KZ := ?; 

   pck_test.Test(r_tmp); 

END;
```

This generated String is used to create a CallableStetment
With the setInt, setString the fields are filled with content before the procedure is called.

With this, everything is working fine. My problems are functions with ROWTYPE.
I have no idea to handle the return value. Functions with normal parameters are no problem with code like this

```
prepareCall("{ ? = call pck_test.func_test(?,?) }");
```

But i need a filled Rowtype parameter.

Any ideas?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for reading.

Comment: Why can't you use the same anonymous block approach? Is it the formal parameter to the function that takes a rowtype, or the return value that is a rowtype?

Comment: if i change the gerneratet Srcipt to use a function like this:

`DECLARE 
   r_tmp Test_table%ROWTYPE; 
   s_ret number;
BEGIN  
   r_tmp.ID := ?; 
   r_tmp.YFE_ID := ?; 
   r_tmp.KZ := ?; 

   s_ret := pck_test.Test(r_tmp); 
   return s_ret;
END;`

I get Exceptions from the Database because a script like this (declare, Begin,end) can't have a return value. It is handled like a procedure. The Return value is only a number or varchar, the parameter for the function is a rowtype and can be a out Parameter, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to test this at the moment but it looks like you want to have an anonymous block generated as:

```
DECLARE 
   r_tmp Test_table%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN  
   r_tmp.ID := ?; 
   r_tmp.YFE_ID := ?; 
   r_tmp.KZ := ?; 

   ? := pck_test.Test(r_tmp);
END;
```

And then call it the same way you did with the procedure call; set the first three bind variables with `setInt()` etc., register the fourth as an output parameter, and retrieve the result with `getInt(4)`.

Comment: Great Anwser, so simple but the best. 
To skip the return Statement and use a placholder for the returnvalue.
This works. Tanks a lot.